# Getting rid of auto-filled zeroes in 2d Java array

Tags: java, arrays

The user inputs numbers with a max of 20 per line and 50 lines. The problem is that if the user inputs less than 20 integers on a line, the array is filled with zeros in the empty spaces so that there is 20 total. This impacts my calculations done with the array.

Does anyone know of an efficient way to get rid of those zeros so that only the original inputted numbers remain?

```
//Extracting/reading from file
public void readFile(File file) {

    try {
        //creates scanner to read file
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(file);

        //set initial count (of rows) to zero
        int maxrows = 0;

        //sets columns to 20 (every row has 20 integers - filled w zeros if not 20 inputted)
        int maxcolumns = 20;

        // goes through file and counts number of rows to set array parameter for length
        while (scn.hasNextLine()) {
            maxrows++;
            scn.nextLine();
        }

        // create array of counted size
        int[][] array = new int[maxrows][maxcolumns];

        //new scanner to reset (read file from beginning again)
        Scanner scn2 = new Scanner(file);

        //places integers one by one into array
        for (int row = 0; row < maxrows; row++) {
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(scn2.nextLine());
            //checks if row has integers
            if (lineScan.hasNextInt()) {

                for (int column = 0; lineScan.hasNextInt(); column++) {
                    array[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next());
                }

            } else System.out.println("ERROR: Row " + (row + 1) + " has no integers.");
        }
        rawData = array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code? How do you transform the integer to a row within the array?

Comment: Think of it as an array of arrays, rather than a 2D array. Create each row only when you know how big it needs to be.

Comment: @Marc updated w the code

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `List`s instead.  Since you admit that you don't know how many elements are going to be inserted, we can simply grow out the list with however many things the user wants to add.

```
// Initialize the initial capacity of your dataMatrix to "maxRows",
// which is NOT a hard restriction on the size of the list
List<List<Integer>> dataMatrix = new ArrayList<>(maxrows);

// When you want to add new elements to that, you must create a new `List` first...

for (int row = 0 ; row < maxrows ; row++) {
    if (lineScan.hasNextInt()) {
        List<Integer> matrixRow = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int column = 0; lineScan.hasNextInt(); column++) {
            dataMatrix.add(Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next()));
        }
        // ...then add the list to your dataMatrix.
        dataMatrix.add(matrixRow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Java labguage [Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), all the elements of array will be initialized with '0' value if array is of type `int`.

However, if you want to differentiate between `0` that is input by user and `0` that is assigned by default, I would recommend using array of `Integer` class so that all the values are initialized with `null`, although that would need changing in code (i.e. to check for `null` value before casting it in `int` literal), e.g:

```
Integer[][] array = new Integer[maxrows][maxcolumns];
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you cany create ArrayList of ArrayList instead of 2d Arrays.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(maxrows);
```

Now you can dynamicaly assign value based on input values, so no extra zero added to data if it contains less than 20 in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `ArrayList<Integer>`s when I need a varying number of integers.

If you must have an array, either set everything to -1 (if -1 is an invalid/sentinel input), or count how many times the user inputs numbers. Then you'd just need to stop when you reach the -1, or exceed the number of inputs.